# How to update a SurfaceView between fixed intervals in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a little program based on the LunarLander example project. What I want to achieve is to update my `SurfaceView` (reposition some `Drawable`s mainly) between fixed intervals like this one:

```
private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000 / 20; // 20 FPS
```

I'm running a `Thread` which is doing this in its `run()` method:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        while (isRunning) {
            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = view.getSurfaceHolder().lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (view.getSurfaceHolder()) {
                    if (GameState.RUNNING.equals(state)) {
                        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        if (now - lastUpdate > UPDATE_INTERVAL) {
                            lastUpdate = now;
                            updater.updatePieces();
                        }
                        doDraw(c);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    view.getSurfaceHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that it is possible that this `Thread` is busy waiting for the `(now - lastUpdate > UPDATE_INTERVAL)` condition to be `true`. But there is an other case if redrawing takes more than 1000 / 20 seconds. This means that the animation is not always seamless. I tried it out in my emulator and it is usually OK but sometimes my `Drawable` is slowing down and after that it speeds up for approximately a half second. Is this just the emulator or something else?

I won't bother you with the details, `updatePieces()` just moves a little circle from top to bottom. I'm not creating any new objects. I somehow get the feeling that this piece of code is not right. Is this a good practice for animating `Drawable`s or I'm missing something obvious? I'm kind of new in this topic.

I propagate touch and key events from the UI thread to this one so I don't really want to call `sleep()` in this `Thread` because it may cause the UI thread to become unresponsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about how objects react in reality. An object moves a certain distance. The distance it will move in a certain amount of time is dependent on a velocity. Velocity is dependent on the very last acceleration. Distance, velocity and acceleration all depends on time.

In your code, you do not deal with time *at all* and therefore there is no real world interpretation to your current code. Put together your physics like this:

1. Implement a delta system, like Euler integration. This system should contain information about how long time it took to draw the previous frame. *NOTE: The Euler integration is accurate when the acceleration is constant, like gravity, and not when acceleration changes. But that is more of an optimization topic, don't consider this issue right now.*
2. When you know how long the previous frame took, you also know the time when your object(s) did not move at all.
3. Consider that time in the next update.

For example:

```
public void updatePieces(float timeDelta) {
    // The amount of an acceleration depends on a force
    // in a specified direction. You can skip this, and just
    // give your object a velocity. But to consider acceleration
    // later on, you have to assign forces and resolve them in
    // their respective direction.
    mAccelerationX  = fResX / weight;             
    mAccelerationY  = fResY / weight; 

    // Consider the previous velocity and add the change
    // in velocity.
    mVelocityX = mVelocityX + (mAccelerationX * timeDelta);
    mVelocityY = mVelocityY + (mAccelerationY * timeDelta);

    mPositionX = mPositionX + (mVelocityX * timeDelta);
    mPositionY = mPositionY + (mVelocityY * timeDelta);
}
```

Knowing a little physics help to understand why this makes sense:

```
mAccelerationX  = fResX / weight;
```

is basically [Newton's second law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion), `F = ma`.

```
mVelocityX = mVelocityX + (mAccelerationX * timeDelta);
```

works because what we're doing is to multiply acceleration `m/s^2` by time `s`. This will give you how much the velocity has changed since the previous frame. Simple cancellation gives us `(m/s^2)*s  = m*s/s^2 = m/s`. Add the previous velocity and your done.

The same logic applies to:

```
mPositionX = mPositionX + (mVelocityX * timeDelta);
// (m/s)*s  = m*s/s = m
```

Note that you may have to add a scale factor to multiply with in order to make the physics realistic to your screen - like how many pixels equals five meter, or something like that.

There are tons of articles describing this, one for example is [Integration Basics](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/integration-basics/) by Glenn Fiedler. Search and you will find more.

Comment: This makes sense. I don't really care about the framerate anyway as long as it does not drop too low. I only have velocity at the moment, and no acceleration (so it is 1).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, +1!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good practice for doing anything based on time for any system that has other work to do: your code is consuming as much CPU time as possible. What you've coded is called a "busy loop". meaning you're remaining busy when you don't have work to do.

Better options include using a timer/alarm of some type (java Timer, Android AlarmManager) to schedule the work to be done when its time, or calling Thread.sleep() to delay until your next update interval.

Comment: I was thinking about Thread.sleep() but as far as I know it doesn't guarantee that it will wait for the time specified. I'm aware of the busy waiting problem as I stated in my question.

Comment: You're correct, it doesn't guarantee it. If you need a real-time system, get rid of Android completely and use a real-time system instead. Your busy loop also doesn't guarantee real-time response (the system can be busy with other threads when you need the CPU, and since you're consuming as much CPU as you can get, you even make that more likely to be the case).

Comment: So if i `wait()` on a `Timer` I can get close to OK?

Comment: Correct, Timer doesn't work like that -- you install a callback instead. I'm concerned though that your code doesn't seem to be doing its thing inside the UI thread. This might work out for you but if at some point it seems it doesn't you may need to push some of the work into its own runnable and call `runOnUiThread(runnable);` to perform it.

Comment: No this is not in the UI thread but I'm locking the canvas and posting the changes after it.